# How to make Peer Read Only in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

A peer is by default endorsing peer , committing peer as well. I want to make it only committing peer.

Comment: I leave a response, although I don't know why do you call "Read Only" to a committing-only peer. A committer writes in the ledger (both blockchain and state).

Comment: A committer-only peer is a peer that helps to maintain the ledgers (it takes part in the gossip protocol and all those things), but that does not perform endorsements. An endorsement is a chaincode execution "simulation" (simulation because it does not update the state until the transaction is committed inside a block). A chaincode query (read only) is basically an endorsement that is not committed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

- Avoid installing chaincodes on those peers. This way, the peers cannot endorse anything.
- Avoid access to chaincode port (7052 by default) on those peers (or set your `CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS` to a non-accessible endpoint). If you are using external builders and launchers some other considerations must be made.
- Set `endorsingPeer` to `false` in your connection profile for those peers. This is only a client setup to be consistent with your network.

Comment: peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'                                                                                Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"cannot retrieve package for chaincode mycc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0: no such file or directory"

Comment: I don't understand you. You want your peer not to endorse transaction proposals, but you complain when you try to endorse against that peer and it does not allow you to: "Error: endorsement failure during query". What do you want?

Comment: A query is just an endorsement that is not committed. A committing-only peer cannot answer to queries. It only helps to maintain the ledgers. I think you have some miss-concepts.

Comment: i understand your point but i want to make query as well with committing peer.

Comment: I understand your point, but it cannot be done. That's not what a committing-only peer is intended to.